# Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to do a box plot for the following data, I am giving the data in this format so that I can make u understand what I am trying to do, but in actual the only the RHS part is present in a `Data.txt` file

```
A1 -- 1
A1 -- 2
A1 -- 3
A1 -- 4
A1 -- 5
B1 -- 10
B1 -- 11
B1 -- 12
B1 -- 13
B1 -- 14
C1 -- 20
C1 -- 21
C1 -- 22
C1 -- 23
C1 -- 24
A5 -- 1
A5 -- 2
A5 -- 3
A5 -- 4
A5 -- 5
B5 -- 10
B5 -- 11
B5 -- 12
B5 -- 13
B5 -- 14
C5 -- 20
C5 -- 21
C5 -- 22
C5 -- 23
C5 -- 24
A10 -- 1
A10 -- 2
A10 -- 3
A10 -- 4
A10 -- 5
B10 -- 10
B10 -- 11
B10 -- 12
B10 -- 13
B10 -- 14
C10 -- 20
C10 -- 21
C10 -- 22
C10 -- 23
C10 -- 24
```

But the data will actually be present in the Data.txt file like this

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to plot a BoxPlot of A B C, like this

[image]

But I am unable to figure out how to do so in Python as I am just a beginner in it and use C++ for my coding. I will be really grateful if someone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Could you also put in the question what have you tried so far and what issue you are facing?

Comment: Truth to be told, I actually dont know where to start and how to start.

Comment: Any guidance will be really helpful like how to build the logic for the same and how to actually use python to show this boxplot

Comment: How do you know what the category of each value in the text file is if there is no column defining the category? Or is it always the same order of these 45 categories?

Comment: Its always the same order. My c++ code outputs this values in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use seaborn and pandas, and if the file has always the same structure, you can boxplot the file after creating two columns for `A-B-C` and `1-5-10`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", header=None, names=["val"])
df["cat"] = np.tile(np.repeat(["A", "B", "C"], 5), 3)
df["num1_5_10"] = np.repeat([1, 5, 10], 15)

sns.boxplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val", hue="cat", dodge=False)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

If you wanted the connecting lines, it would be just one more line; however, seaborn creates duplicate legend entries for this pointplot. So, if you want to keep the legend, we have to manually remove the duplicates:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", header=None, names=["val"])
df["cat"] = np.tile(np.repeat(["A", "B", "C"], 5), 3)
df["num1_5_10"] = np.repeat([1, 5, 10], 15)

ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val", hue="cat", zorder=0.9, dodge=False)
#add the lines connecting the median values
sns.pointplot(data=df, x="num1_5_10", y="val", hue="cat", estimator=np.median, ci=None, markers="None", ax=ax)

#remove duplicate entries, setting the legend outside the graph, new title
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[:3], labels[:3], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title="C++ for the win")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Strangely enough, seaborn does not respect the order of plotting, so we have to manipulate the `zorder` in the preceding boxplot to get the correct order of graphic elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Is there any way to connect the center of each boxplots of same type by a line like I have shown in the image?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Can u please explain the problem "The main problem is the legend entries after the addition because seaborn creates duplicate entries for all categories" ? I am not able to understand this.

Comment: seaborn does not know that the ABC of the boxplot are the same as the ABC in the pointplot. So, each category appears two times in the legend - one entry for the boxplot, one with the (non-existing) marker for the pointplot. This confuses the readers - for them, there is only one category A. So, we have to remove the second set of entries manually after seaborn has added it to the legend. Maybe one can suppress the second legend entries when seaborn creates the pointplot but I do not know how. So, we adapt the legend retrospectively.

Comment: Ok got it.. :) another question, in the second code u have added 'zorder', but I am not able to see any difference between the first graph and the second graph due to this, what does it actually do?

Comment: Graphic elements in matplotlib like text, axes, labels, titles, etc. have a specific plotting order (apart from their order within the code) that is defined by their `zorder` value. Matplotlib assumes a certain order - lines have, for instance, typically a higher zorder value than polygons because otherwise, the edgeline of an area may be hidden by the plotted area. Seaborn did something strange - the added line for C was plotted in front of the boxplots (as expected) but those for A and B were not. I modified the zorder argument of the boxplot as a workaround. Not optimal, I have to admit.